# Python Creating new columns/attributes across all possible combinations of variables

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

If I have a data frame with variables A, B, C, D, E how can I create a for or while loop to create variables by doing all possible combinations of the existing variables using all variables and all posible mathematical operators (+,-,/,*)?

To go from a data-frame with the following variables:

**A  B  C  D  E**

to one like this:

**A  B  C  D  E  A+B  A+C  A+D A+E A*B  …**

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You want to use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

vars = [1, 2, 3]

np.concatenate([
        np.add.outer(vars, vars),
        np.subtract.outer(vars, vars),
        np.multiply.outer(vars, vars),
        np.divide.outer(vars, vars)]).flatten()
```

Looks like:

```
array([ 2,  3,  4,  3,  4,  5,  4,  5,  6,  0, -1, -2,  1,  0, -1,  2,  1,
        0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  4,  6,  3,  6,  9,  1,  0,  0,  2,  1,  0,  3,
        1,  1])
```

## Explanation

```
# All possible additions
print np.add.outer(vars, vars)

# All possible subtractions
print np.subtract.outer(vars, vars)

# All possible multiplications
print np.multiply.outer(vars, vars)

# All possible divisions
print np.divide.outer(vars, vars)
```

Looks like this:

```
[[2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]
 [4 5 6]]

[[ 0 -1 -2]
 [ 1  0 -1]
 [ 2  1  0]]

[[1 2 3]
 [2 4 6]
 [3 6 9]]

[[1 0 0]
 [2 1 0]
 [3 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `product` and `eval` to evaluate every possible combination.  These are saved using a dictionary comprehension, and then concatenated back with the original data.

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [5, 6]})

transformations = {"".join(p): eval("df.loc[:, '{0}'] {1} df.loc[:, '{2}']".format(*p))
                   for p in product(df, list('+-/*'), df)}
transformations = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(transformations)], axis=1)

>>> transformations
   A  B  C  A+A  A+B  A+C  A-A  A-B  A-C  A/A ...   C+C  C-A  C-B  C-C  C/A  C/B  C/C  C*A  C*B  C*C
0  1  3  5    2    4    6    0   -2   -4    1 ...    10    4    2    0    5    2    1    5   15   25
1  2  4  6    4    6    8    0   -2   -4    1 ...    12    4    2    0    3    2    1   12   24   36

[2 rows x 39 columns]
```

Comment: use of `eval` is not encouraged

Answer (score 0):

Loops are not the most efficient method for achieving this. However, I assume that on this occasion, there is point/necessity in using them.

So, assuming from you've said that you want to conduct an element-wise operation using nothing but iterations (loops) and no 3rd party libraries. We can do this efficiently (or as efficiently as we can) using generators. This is how I would go about it:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

operations = {
    "+": lambda x,y: (value+y for value in x), 
    "-": lambda x,y: (value-y for value in x), 
    "*": lambda x,y: (value*y for value in x), 
    "/": lambda x,y: (value/y for value in x),
}

calculations = (
    (key, val, oper(data, val)) 
    for key, oper in sorted(operations.items()) 
    for val in data
)
```

Now let's display the results:

```
for item in calculations:
    op, val, res = item
    preped_res = str.join(
        ' | ', ["{:^6.2g}".format(val) for val in res]
    )

    print(" {}  {}  {:.2g}  = | {} |".format(data, op, val, preped_res))
```

which would look like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  *  1  = |   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  *  2  = |   2    |   4    |   6    |   8    |   10   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  *  3  = |   3    |   6    |   9    |   12   |   15   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  *  4  = |   4    |   8    |   12   |   16   |   20   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  *  5  = |   5    |   10   |   15   |   20   |   25   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  +  1  = |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  +  2  = |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6    |   7    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  +  3  = |   4    |   5    |   6    |   7    |   8    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  +  4  = |   5    |   6    |   7    |   8    |   9    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  +  5  = |   6    |   7    |   8    |   9    |   10   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  -  1  = |   0    |   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  -  2  = |   -1   |   0    |   1    |   2    |   3    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  -  3  = |   -2   |   -1   |   0    |   1    |   2    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  -  4  = |   -3   |   -2   |   -1   |   0    |   1    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  -  5  = |   -4   |   -3   |   -2   |   -1   |   0    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  /  1  = |   1    |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  /  2  = |  0.5   |   1    |  1.5   |   2    |  2.5   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  /  3  = |  0.33  |  0.67  |   1    |  1.3   |  1.7   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  /  4  = |  0.25  |  0.5   |  0.75  |   1    |  1.2   |
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  /  5  = |  0.2   |  0.4   |  0.6   |  0.8   |   1    |
```

Hope this answers your question. But if there's anything I have missed, please feel free to tell me and we shall see what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, `reindex` and `itertools` are your friends

```
In [21]: import pandas as pd

In [22]: import numpy as np

In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':np.arange(5), 'c':np.arange(5)
    ...: })

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4

In [26]: operations = ['*', '/', '-', '+']

In [30]: new_columns = list(''.join([a,b,c]) for a,b,c in itertools.product(s1,s2,s1) if a!=c ) # joins the permutations of the three elements, and returns those where the first is not repeated i.e. a*a, b-b, etc. You can remove the last if to get all of them

In [31]: new_columns
Out[31]: 
['a*b',
 'a*c',
 'a/b',
 'a/c',
 'a-b',
 'a-c',
 'b*a',
 'b*c',
 'b/a',
 'b/c',
 'b-a',
 'b-c',
 'c*a',
 'c*b',
 'c/a',
 'c/b',
 'c-a',
 'c-b']

In [33]: df.reindex(columns=[*df.columns, *new_columns], fill_value=np.nan) # rewrites the df using by unpacking the existing columns, and also the new columns. Fill the new empty places with `NaN`.
Out[33]: 
   a  b  c  a*b  a*c  a/b  a/c  a-b  a-c  b*a ...   b/a  b/c  b-a  b-c  c*a  \
0  0  0  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1  1  1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
2  2  2  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
3  3  3  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
4  4  4  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   

   c*b  c/a  c/b  c-a  c-b  
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

You can change the function `''.join()` by any you would like and obtain the same result.